# Scipy fmin optimize function with conditions

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

Let's say I have a function that behaves differently (i.e: by using conditions) for the values of the data. Is it possible to optimize such a function using `fmin` so as to find a value that maximizes the output?

This is why I currently have:

```
def bogus_function(x):
    if x[0] > 5 or x[1] > 5:
        return 20
    elif x[1] > 2:
        return x[0]*x[1]
    else:
        return -1

test = lambda x: -bogus_function(x)
results = fmin(test,[0,0])
```

This is where it gets "stuck", because printing the results and looking at the optimization process, the algorithm tries the same initial guess without changing the values.

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 1.000000
     Iterations: 16
     Function evaluations: 63

>>> results
(array([ 0.,  0.]),
 [array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.]),
  array([ 0.,  0.])])
```

In this case, the `bogus_function` optimal values are: [5,5], which makes the final maximum value equal to 25. Any idea if that kind of optimization is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, x=[0, 0] qualifies as a local minimum: you move a bit away from it, and the value of the function does not change. 
You probably want something non-constant.

In general, what matters for many optimization algorithms is whether your function is continuous/differentiable. Some algorithms can deal with the lack of smoothness, some not.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function so that it is continuous and used minimize with SLSQP method for placing bounds on the inputs.